# What's the general equivalence of the second fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Now I know that the first fundamental form is actually what we call a metric tensor and be generalized into manifolds $M^n$, is there an  equivalence for the second form? I know that we use it to calculate the Gauss curvature  ect. Just curious how it's related to the generalization (if it is).

Comment: There isn't. The second fundamental form is only defined when $M$ is a submanifold of another Riemannian manifold.

Comment: The point is that curvature is defined intrinsically in general, not extrinsically. The Theorema Egregium tells you that even for surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ you can determine the Gaussian curvature (as you know it extrinsically) in terms of just the metric and its derivatives.